# What is the significance of this twirly pe?

Tags: hebrew

The picture below shows two examples of the letter pe.  They are both written on the same piece of vellum, in Genesis 23.  One pe is written normally, whereas one has a twirl.  What's the significance of the twirl?

[image]

This is the only place occurrence of the twirly pe on this sheet of vellum.  I have some sections of other scrolls, however, where the twirly pe is used extensively.  Maybe half the pes are given this flourish, while the other half are written normally.

Comment: I believe (although I can't be sure since I'm not an expert) that the torah in front of you is using what is known as "Beit Yosef-Maharal" script. It is very very rare - I've only seen one other torah in my life that used it, which is one of the reasons I'm not sure.